# Multiplicites of roots of $x^{p^k}-x$ ($p$ is prime) in $L[x]$ with $L$ as an extension of $Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, factoring

The following is from A. Białynicki-Birula, "Algebra" (the translation is mine).

(Chapter VI, \$6).

> Example 1. Let $K$ be a field and let $b \in K, b \neq 0$. Let us consider the polynomial $x^n - b$. We will prove that if $\chi(K) = 0$, then every root of this polynomial has multiplicity equal to 1, and if $\chi(K) = p \neq 0$, then each root of this polynomial has multiplicity equal to $p^m$, where $p^m$ is the greatest power of $p$ such that $p^m \mid n$.

**Remark:**  In the below text the author indeed wrote "see chapter IV, $6, example 1". It is clearly a mistake as there is no such example and that chapter is "Dimension" (of linear space). For this reason I suppose that he wanted to refer to what I quoted above.

(Chapter X. Algebraic elements; \$4. The field of polynomial factorization)

> **Theorem 4.1.** For every field $K$ and for every polynomial $f \in K[x]$ of degree greater than 0 there exists such an extension $L$ of field $K$ that the polynomial $f$ has factorization into linear factors in the ring $L[x]$ .

> **Example 1.** Let $p$ be a prime number and $k$ a natural number. Theorem 4.1 implies that there exists an extension $L$ of the field $Z_p$ such that the polynomial $x^{p^k} - x$ has factorization into linear factors in the ring $L[x]$. Thus in the ring $L[x]$ we have
> $$x^{p^k}-x = (x-e_1)(x-e_2)...(x-e_q),\ \ \ \ \ \ \ q=p^k.$$
> For every two elements $e_i$, $e_j$ such that $i \neq j$ the condition $e_i \neq e_j$ holds and every root of the polynomial $x^{p^k} - x$ in the field $L$ is equal to $e_k$ for some $k = 1, ..., q$ (see chapter IV, $6, example 1) . (...)

How does the statement of the first example allow us to conclude that for each $i, j$ the fact $i \neq j$ implies that $e_i \neq e_j$? I have tried to prove it in several ways but with no success. I tried to establish that $x^n - b$ in some way gathers all the roots so $x^{p^k} - x$ "has exactly one in its disposal" ($p^m \cdot 1 = p^m$), use powers to get $p^m$ same factors in the factorization of $x^{p^k}-x$ and so on but I can't establish a (sufficient) relation between $x^{p^k} - x$ and $x^n - b$ in this case. 
All what I obtained is that:

1. every root $a$ of $x^{p^k} - x$ is a root of $x^{p^k} - a$,
2. if $a$ is a root of $x^{p^k} - x$, then this polynomial cannot be factored in $(x-a)^{p^k}$ as polynomials $x^{p^k} - x$ and $x^{p^k}-a$ are different.
   From some searching on the Internet, I have seen that proofs of the concerned fact generally use derivative, but I read almost whole book and I'm almost sure that he does not use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I deleted my initial answer, because it seems I misunderstood the question a bit when I wrote that.

If one is already given the result in Example $1$ from Chapter $6$, then the statement in Example $1$ following Theorem $4.1$ is fairly easy to prove.

The idea is essentially just to factor $f(x)=x^{p^k}-x$ as $x(x^{p^k-1}-1)$. Clearly $0$ is not a root of $x^{p^k}-1$, so $0$ is not a repeated root of $f(x)$. This means exactly one of the $e_i$s, say $e_1$ WLOG, is $0$. This gives us $x^{p^k-1}-1=(x-e_2)(x-e_3)\dots(x-e_q)$, so it is enough to show that $x^{p^k-1}-1$ has no repeated roots. But this is trivial, as the highest power of $p$ dividing $p^k-1$ is obviously $p^0=1$, so by Chapter $6$, Example $1$, all roots of $x^{p^k}-1$ have multiplicity $1$ (remember we are working in an extension of $\mathbb Z_p$), i.e. all of $e_2,e_3,\dots,e_q$ are distinct. It follows that all $e_i$s are distinct, as desired.

Again, apologies for the initial complicated answer and any confusion it caused. The material there was largely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks very much for your current answer and for the previous one, too! Your previous answer indeed allowed me to come up in the meantime with the proof on my own as it turned my attention to quite different things than I'd been trying. I think that it was when you wrote about formal derivative and $nx^{n-1}$, it turned my attention to the factorization of the polynomial as $x(x^{n-1} - 1)$. I tried it earlier but this time I at last saw the connection with the quoted example and I realized that it is necessary just to show that $n-1$ and $p$ are coprime.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd rather keep my previous answer deleted as it will be very confusing to anyone else and not very relevant, but if you think it is of some use I can send it to you.